# Limit of integral of difference between f(x) & f(x+h)

Tags: calculus, limits

If $f(x)$ is defined on $[0,1]$,

Given that $f(x)$ is integrable on $[0,1]$, is the following limit true for all $c$ with $0 ≤ c < 1$?

$$
\lim_{h\to0^+}\int_0^c\bigl(f(x+h)-f(x)\bigr)\,dx=0
$$

Since we're not given anything about $f(x)$, I'm not sure how to use the continuity of the integral, if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you allowed to use the substitution rule? If you are, you could split the difference, transform the first integral to $\int_{h}^{c+h} f(x) dx$, and apply some limit theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you done any measure theory? As $f$ is integrable, you can use Cauchy-Schwarz and the Dominated Convergence Theorem to bring the limit inside the integral. Now while $f$ need not be continuous, as it is integrable you can approximate it arbitrarily well by a continuous function, and you are integrating over a finite interval.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{h\rightarrow0^+}\int_0^c(f(x+h)-f(x))dx = \lim_{h\rightarrow0^+}\int_0^ch\cdot\frac{(f(x+h)-f(x))}{h}dx$$ $$= \lim_{h\rightarrow0^+}\int_0^ch\cdot f'(x)dx = \lim_{h\rightarrow0^+}h\cdot\int_0^cf'(x)dx = \lim_{h\rightarrow0^+}h\cdot (f(c)-f(0)) = 0$$
Did I miss something why this doesn't work?

Comment: There's no differentiability hypothesis, to begin with.